# UITabBarItem with variable destination view

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have 4 tab bar items (the buttons at the bottom of the screen) and I need the last one to do display a different view depending on certain properties.

If the user has a specific property, touching this tab bar item will move on to a UINavigationController.
If the user does not have a specific property, touching this tab bar will move on to a UIViewController with a WebView.

I'm using Storyboard and targeting iOS6.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't it's possible to have a tab bar item dynamically move to different `UIViewControllers`. What you could do, however, is have two separate view controllers that have identical-looking `UITabBarItems`, and add/remove them appropriately by modifying the `viewControllers` property of the `UITabBarController`. According to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/viewControllers, no animation occurs when changing the `viewControllers` property, so to the user it should appear as though nothing happened when the `viewControllers` changed, but the `UITabBarItem` will now redirect to a different `UIViewController`.

Comment: yeah that is one approach, I just don't like to add/remove tab bar items at runtime.

Comment: Hey Kamaros, I'm trying your suggestion and I can get the tab items correctly but then the view shows just black.

In my TabBarController.m:
    if ( !member)
    {
        NotMemberVC *vc = [[NotMemberVC alloc]init];
        vc.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"door-sign.png"] tag:0];
        
        [newArrayOfControllers removeLastObject];
        [newArrayOfControllers addObject:vc];
        
        self.viewControllers = newArrayOfControllers;
    }
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

First, in your Storyboard, make a relationship between your UITabBarController and a UINavigationController (we will be using the same UINavigationController for the fourth bar item regardless if the user has our `specialProperty`). Make the rootViewController of the UINavigationController be the custom UIViewController that presets your UIWebView (you can hide the navigation bar in your storyboard if you choose).

Then, make a custom subclass of UITabBarController if you have not done so already and set your UITabBarController in your storyboard to use this class (in my example, we will call this class MyTabBarController). You will need to override `prepareSegue:sender:` in this class.

For example:

```
@interface MyTabBarController : UITabBarController
@end

@implementation MyTabBarController

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // get destination UIViewController
    id controller = segue.destinationViewController;
    // check if the destination has a rootViewController property
    if ([controller respondsToSelector:@selector(setRootViewController:)]) {
        // check your special property
        if ([controller specialProperty]) {
            // init the root of your UINavigationController
            UIViewController *specialController = [[MySpecialViewController alloc] init];
            [controller setRootViewController:specialController];
            // if you are not using ARC, call [specialController release] here
            // if you hid the navigation bar for your default controller in storyboard, show it
            [controller setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
        } else {
            // do some custom configuration of your controller without the special property
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@ does not have a root view controller to override.",controller);
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me play with this and I'll get back to you.

Comment: If you created your `MySpecialViewController` that you want as the base of the UINavigation controller in your Storyboard, you can instantiate it in code by assigning a storyboard identifier for the view controller in your storyboard and calling `[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MSVCIndentifier"]` (changing the strings to match the name of your storyboard and the identifier for your view controller of course).